# Laravel Eloquent ORM GroupBy() and also return

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have a table room_details. Now, I am simply identifying month wise data which is grouped by location and count office_location_id, How can I write MySql query for this?

Here is that I want:

```
Month------Location------office_location_id
January----location 1 --- 11
February---location 3 --- 25
March------location 4 --- 40
```

Here is my table:

[image]

Comment: where are the location and month in your table schema?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where month and location data are, but you can write your query like the example that I write below:

```
SELECT COUNT(office_location_id), month, location
FROM table_name
GROUP BY month;
```